# Createing and calling events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a choose your own adventure game written entirely in HTML and Javascript; I want to create most of my elements entirely in Javascript to create an awesome dynamic game! I am having trouble using events and event listeners. It's a mystery game; after the player chooses their character from a list, they can invite five guests to a party. One of the guests is killed, leaving you to solve the mystery with three suspects.

After you've selected your player, there's another button that says "Select this character!". When this button is clicked, the player creation UI is supposed to be hidden, and a new UI is visible. With the code as it is now, the "StartGame" function is skipped entirely. What am I doing wrong? Any help you can give would be seriously awesome and greatly appreciated!

```
btnPlayer = document.createElement('button');
btnPlayer.id = 'BTN_btnPlayer';
btnPlayer.type = 'button';
btnPlayer.addEventListener('click', welcomePlayer(), true);
btnPlayer.onclick = welcomePlayer();
btnPlayer.innerHTML = 'Select This Character!';
myDiv.appendChild(btnPlayer);
```

**EDIT**
I modified my button event properties to look like this:

```
btnPlayer.addEventListener('click', welcomePlayer, true);
//btnPlayer.onclick = welcomePlayer;
```

One is commented out because neither has worked. I tried clearing my cache, too. Here is my StartGame() function with the button code excluded. I won't include the "charFirstNames[]" and "charLastNames[]" used to create the choices in my dropdownlist. I have them separated in order to tell a more interesting story; they will eventually be database records when I get the bugs and the basics worked out. I don't think I messed up anything up here, but is it possible that I did? The function is called by the only button coded into the HTML.

```
function startGame(divName) {
myDiv = document.getElementById('story');

lblPlayer = document.createElement('label');
lblPlayer.id = 'LBL_Player';
lblPlayer.htmlFor = 'DDL_PlayerChar';
lblPlayer.innerHTML = 'Please select a character. ';
myDiv.appendChild(lblPlayer);

ddlPlayer = document.createElement('select');
ddlPlayer.id = 'DDL_PlayerChar';
myDiv.appendChild(ddlPlayer);

defOpt = document.createElement("option");
defOpt.value = 0;
defOpt.text = 'Select...';
ddlPlayer.appendChild(defOpt);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < charFirstNames.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = charFirstNames[i]+'_'+charLastNames[i];
    option.text = charFirstNames[i]+' '+charLastNames[i];
    ddlPlayer.appendChild(option);
}

document.getElementById('BTN_Start').hidden = true;
```

}

The welcomePlayer() function is similar to the startgame() function, creating the interface to invite the first "guest" and removing the player creation UI.

Comment: What "StartGame" function?

Comment: `btnPlayer.addEventListener('click', welcomePlayer(), true);` should be `btnPlayer.addEventListener('click', welcomePlayer, true);` without the (). When you add parenthesis the function is evoked immediately rather than waiting for the even tto trigger it. You are also adding the event 2x, once through the event listener and once through `onclick` (which again shouldn't have the () as that immediately invokes the function). Pick a method and stick with it.

Comment: @scrappedcola although I highly doubt it, if `welcomePlayer` returns a closure it's still working code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these lines set the `onclick` handler to the result of calling the `welcomePlayer` function (see the parens?).

```
btnPlayer.addEventListener('click', welcomePlayer(), true);
btnPlayer.onclick = welcomePlayer();
```

You probably mean

```
btnPlayer.addEventListener('click', welcomePlayer, true);
```

Comment: So I need to create the function as a variable? `var welcomePlayer = function () { //code here };

Comment: @Shortstuff81000 it should work the same either way.

Comment: @Shortstuff81000 It doesn't matter here whether you do `var welcomePlayer = function() {}` or `function welcomePlayer() {}`. The former is a *variable assignment* (available only to code initialized after it, and subject to *function scope*), while the latter is a *function declaration* (defined immediately, globally, and available to all code).